# Reading .ply File Manually

Tags: object, vertices, ply-file-format

I'm jumping into the world of .ply files. I've read a little bit about them but the documentation regarding their formatting doesn't quite seem to line up with what I have in my file. I've been trying to make sense of this article [here](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/ply/) but I'm not having much luck.

This is what my .ply file looks like, format wise:

```
element vertex 940
property float x
property float y
property float z
property float nx
property float ny
property float nz
property float s
property float t
element face 1559
property list uchar uint vertex_indices
end_header
0.106050 -0.077401 2.338200 -0.234779 0.430097 -0.871700 0.766400 1.131300
0.093450 -0.093151 2.345250 -0.618366 0.706809 -0.343486 0.742100 1.116300
0.106050 -0.075601 2.355600 -0.792810 0.606189 -0.062685 0.774600 1.120500
0.096000 -0.103051 2.327850 0.044801 0.552751 -0.832118 0.731200 1.123200
0.057600 -0.110401 2.323950 -0.333872 0.740287 -0.583483 0.726800 1.104800
```

and then after a few hundred lines of that, this:

```
3 0 1 2
3 1 0 3
3 1 3 4
3 4 5 1
3 4 6 5
3 4 7 6
3 4 8 7
3 8 4 3
3 3 9 8
3 3 10 9
3 10 3 0
3 0 11 10
3 11 0 12
3 12 13 11
3 12 14 13
3 14 12 15
3 15 16 14
3 16 15 17
3 17 18 16
3 17 19 18
3 19 17 20
3 20 21 19
3 20 22 21
3 22 20 23
3 22 23 24
```

Like I said, I'm trying to make sense of it so I can write my own program to take the vertices and connect them to reform the object. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLY_(file_format)) has an answer for you.

The ply-file starts with a header, which offers you all relevant information about how to read the data section. Important keywords of the header are `element` and `property`.

The `element` keyword introduces a new section, which describes data. There are two of them in your example. The first to store the vertex data and the other one to store the face data.

The `property` keyword introduces a new property of this data section. It is followed by the type and the kind of the data. `x`, `y` and `z` refer to vertex position information, `nx`, `ny` and `nz` to normal information which belong to the vertex and `s` and `t` are the texture coordinates for the vertex. The information in the data block is stored in the order of appearence.

The other data block is charaterized by the line

```
property list uchar uint vertex_indices
```

The first unknown keyword is `list`, which indicates that the data of the property `vertex_indices` are stored in a list. `uchar` refers to the data type, which stores the number of list entries for this property and `uint` is the type of ech list entry. Let's have look at your example:

```
3 0 1 2
```

- `3` is from type `uchar` and indicates that there are three list entries (so this face is a triangle)
- `0 1 2` are the indices of the vertices (from the data block above) and from type unsigned integer

Answer (score 1):

I found a demo application in java, which renders exactly this format: it is called jply and can be found on GITHUB:
https://github.com/smurn/jPLY 
There are also these examples:
http://quabr.com/19609248/rendering-ply-files-in-opengl
http://1987.io/questions/2365561/android-and-opengl-how-display-faces

Hope it might help.

Answer (score 0):

Is is possible to store normal of each face (face:- formed by typically 3 vertices ). Inside the .ply file .